# Chartkick bar chart: specify which series to display

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, chartkick

How do you go about specifying the series to display in a Chartkick bar chart?

Currently I have:

```
<%= bar_chart User.group(:user_type).count %>
```

Which works great.  Say, however, that I have 3 different types of users: A, B, C.  How do I only display A and B within the Chartkick bar chart?

Answer (score 2):

And the answer is:

```
<%= bar_chart User.group(:user_type).where(:user_type => ["A", "B"]).count %>
```